# quickbooks getting class details

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to get all the details of CLASS, I am getting response as empty i.e [], I am following this document to get the class details.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/class

1) Is there any sample java code exists to get the CLASS details? At present I am using mule esb to get class details. I have created a sample application in intuit which is a 1 month free usage.

2) Can I get class details, create class, update and query class from the free version of application?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the java devkit from here - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0201_ipp_java_devkit_3.0/0001_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis

actual code(using above devkit) will be something like -

```
this.service.getAll(new Class());
```

2) Can I get class details, create class, update and query class from the free version of application?

If your free version is a QBO plus ? Then you can.
I've not tried this in simpleStart(most probably it doesn't support class tracking) or essential.

Thanks